# $RANDOM in linux bash will alway be the same upon bootup

Tags: linux, bash, random

I ran into this problem and I'm so confused.

I am using $RANDOM in bash as a test string at the very beginning of the linux bootup process. Very interestingly, I observed that $RANDOM will be the same every time linux booted up. In my case, it's 18869.

I was simply echoing $RANDOM to a file. I observed the same number in every boot up. After that, $RANDOM seems to return "real" random numbers.

```
echo "$RANDOM is a test string" >> /tmp/test
```

Can anyone explain the reason in this?

Comment: Look inside `bash` source code. You'll probably find out that `$RANDOM`  is some *pseudo* random number generator (so in fact it is deterministic)!

Answer (score 5):

Here is the initial seed algorithm from `variables.c` in the Bash 4.2 source code:

```
static void                                                                                               
seedrand ()                                                                                               
{                                                                                                         
  struct timeval tv;                                                                                      
                                                                                                          
  gettimeofday (&tv, NULL);                                                                               
  sbrand (tv.tv_sec ^ tv.tv_usec ^ getpid ());                                                            
}
```

In other words, it generates the seed based on pid and current time in seconds and microseconds (with a system accuracy of ~1/100th second).

If you check `$RANDOM` on a small, predictable system, before the system clock is initialized, you're likely to see the same value every time.

Comment: Thanks for the information. In this scenario where the system clock is not initialized on an embedded system, what do you suggest to do to generate a random number?

Comment: Is this embedded system managing /dev/urandom like larger linux distros do? If so, you could ensure your script runs just after /dev/urandom is initialized, and set RANDOM from a few bytes of that data.

Comment: Some embedded systems like Raspberry Pi has a hardware number generator device you could use. You can also write a file periodically or on shutdown that writes `date +%s >> /tmp/seed` and then `RANDOM=$(</tmp/seed)` on boot.

Answer (score 0):

Because the seed is always the same at the startup. You can always assign a value

```
RANDOM=1000
```

to seed the RANDOM manually, perhaps with the PID

```
RANDOM=$$
```

Trying to find your seed, I wrote this small script

```
for ((i=-150000; i<150000 ;i=i+1)); do
  RANDOM=$i;
  echo "$i: $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM";
done | grep "18869[^:]"
```

and found:

```
-118657: 8608 18869 19673
-108446: 18869 18855 15976
-78471: 694 18869 19296
-75678: 18869 23165 7967
-42910: 18869 27476 32727
-38285: 25548 18869 18919
-10142: 18869 31786 24719
27971: 18869 6258 29786
33149: 13707 18869 8396
60739: 18869 10568 21777
73335: 5793 18869 8019
93507: 18869 14878 13769
113521: 30647 18869 7642
126275: 18869 19188 5761
137004: 18869 3793 18604
```

See that this script has lots of `$RANDOM` but still is fully deterministic, it'll result always the same if you call it. **[This link](http://academic.evergreen.edu/s/scottgo/bashguide/html/randomvar.html)** has more information about `$RANDOM` and [this other link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-shell-script-generating-random-numbers/) has information on how to use `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom`, as an alternative. Another way to generate a random number without the seed issue is to get some information about the actual time in nanoseconds.

```
date +%N
```